# Trying to pass the array data using ajax to php function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Trying to pass the array data using ajax to the PHP function. but getting null value. I am using post method to pass the data.

```
$(document).on('change','#accordion',function(){
            filter = [];

            $('input[name^=\'filter\']:checked').each(function(element) {

                filter.push(this.value);
            });

           var params = new window.URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
           var search = params.get('search');

           $.ajax({
               url:"index.php?route=product/search/filtered_data",
               method:"POST",
               data:{filter:filter},
               success:function(data){
                 console.log("Hitesh"+data);
               }
           });
        });
```

PHP Code

```
public function filtered_data(){

  $filter = isset($_POST["filter"]);
        echo json_encode($filter);
}
```

Comment: `$filter = isset($_POST["filter"]);` should be: `$filter = isset($_POST["filter"]) ? $_POST['filter'] : [];`. Right now, you're storing (and encoding) the response of [isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php), which is a boolean.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson But its giving me empty array

Comment: Then you need to debug your code to see where it fails. Add a `console.log(filter)` after your `.each()` and check what it actually contains. If that looks correct, you need to check the network tab in the browsers development tools while making the ajax request to see what data it actually sends to the server. I don't see the purpose of your `params` and `search` variables though? You don't seem to use them for anything.